# JSP: How to refer to current element

Tags: html, css, jsp, jsp-tags

I am very new to JSP and trying to refer the current active element. I am using Pega BPM and trying to write a custom control using JSP. All I am looking for is how to refer to the current active element. I want to apply red color to the current active element. I tried using the following but no luck -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var colorField=document.getElementById(this);
colorField.style.color=red;
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Current element is something i have in focus

**EDIT 2:** The html looks something like the following. I need to change the color of test value to red. This is an autogenerated html so i need to write a jsp/html on my side to change the color --

```
<div class="content-item content-paragraph item-1 flex " style="" data-ui-meta="{'type':'Çell'}">test value</div>
```

There many other elements within the class content-item content-paragraph which follow the pattern as -

```
content-item content-paragraph item-2
content-item content-paragraph item-3
content-item content-paragraph item-4
```

.....

Comment: In your code, `this` is the current window because your code is not inside an event handler. `ById` gives you a hint. You need `var colorField=document.getElementById('IdOfColorField');` where you replac IdOfColorField with the actual ID you can see in the view-source or some JSP variable. PS: There is no JSP in your code at all

Comment: so thats what my question is- any way to get the id of the current element? I am trying make this JSP dynamic by referring the current element.. Got it that this refers to current window but any way to refer to current element?

Comment: What is "current element" Something you have focussed? Then you need to do something like `var elements = document.querySelectorAll('tagname'); for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) { elements[i].onclick=function() { this.style.color="red"; }}` - replace tagname with for example 'div' or 'input' or '.className' - note that inside the onclick handler, `this` is the element

Comment: Yes, I mean something i have focused. Above does not really help. Any way to get element id dynamically? like i don't know what is the element id.

Comment: You have posted far too little code/information for me to answer your question. My code accesses elements by type or class to not need an ID. Please post rendered HTML with expected result in a [mcve]

Comment: I have edited. Will the code help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163570/discussion-between-chandeep-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I’m not near a computer

Comment: can you comment here ?

Comment: “I need to write a JSP to change the color.” Are you sure you understand the difference between JSP Java Server Pages that executes on the server and JavaScript client based code that runs in the browser?

Comment: yeah :) i know that. So what are you coming at? writing a JavaScript is not the solution here ?

Comment: I do not have enough information to tell you. You have auto generated html. If you have that in a string on the server you can add a style to the html using string or html DOM manipulation on the server. You can ALSO pass it to the client and include JavaScript to change it. I still have no idea of your setup or what is rendering where or what “current” means

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what you mean, but here is an example of what I think you mean

```js
window.onload=function() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".content-item");
  console.log(divs.length)
  for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
    divs[i].onclick=function() {
      console.log(this.innerHTML)
      this.style.color="red";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-item content-paragraph item-1 flex">test value 1</div>
<div class="content-item content-paragraph item-2 flex">test value 2</div>
<div class="content-item content-paragraph item-3 flex">test value 3</div>
<div class="content-item content-paragraph item-4 flex">test value 4</div>
<div class="content-item content-paragraph item-5 flex">test value 5</div>
```